# how to add a library into a new library project in Visual Studio c\c++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, dll, static-libraries

I know how to add a dll or static library into my project but recently i have come to a situation that i need to add a dll library into my new dll/static library project (i have NOT decided yet:)) and i cannot follow the same way i did with "ordinary" prjects like `properties->c\c++->general->additional....`
but i don`t see any LINK category in properties?!. Can you please help me find that "LINK":) or show me how to do that in another way? 
I am working with c/c++ by the way:)

**EDIT:** i am including my lib but can`t link it and show which lib i need to use like Link->input .... my.lib

Comment: Generally a static library is simply an archive of object files. It's not linked and therefore it makes no sense to add libraries. If your static library depends on other libraries, those other libraries have to be linked together with your library when creating the executable program. A DLL on the other hand is basically a special variant of an executable program, and therefore it needs to be linked similar to a program, with external libraries being linked into the DLL.

Comment: On a different point, there is no "C/C++" language. Unless you have a project with a mix of C and C++ source files, or are making comparisons between the C and C++ languages, use only one of the language tags. For this question, the actual language is not really relevant though. So you could remove both and then add the `language-agnostic` tag instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. Can you tell me if this is possible to add a dll dib int dll lib project in visual studio working with c and/or c++

Comment: i meant lib insead dib:)

Comment: In VS: 1st: A VS project may be configured to generate an exe, a lib, or a dll. 2nd: You may configure a VS solution which contains multiple VS projects. 3rd: You may configure project dependencies e.g. exe built by project 1 depends on dll built by project 2. If done right VS cares about re-building your project 1 if something relevant changes in project 2. - Unfortunately, I cannot remember how to setup this manually (as we use CMake for years.) I'm sure you should find a doc. on MSDN concerning this.

Comment: It depends on project output directory settings, whether you can start debugging of the exe by simply pressing F5 (or clicking the Debug button). If output directory of exe and dll are identical (as it is configured e.g. by CMake) then the exe will find the dll. If not, you might have to tell this in the environment settings of the exe project properties (e.g. setting/extending the `PATH` env. var.)